# Setting up GitHub webhooks for an OpenShift build

Tags: github, build, openshift, webhooks, redhat-containers

I tried to set up a github webhook to trigger builds on OpenShift following [these docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html).

I am confused about two things:

(1) When I create the secret, as prescribed by the above docs, do I need to create one YAML entry or two? Ie. are the following snippets (taken from the above link) supposed to be the same YAML entry?

```
type: "GitHub"
github:
  secretReference:
    name: "mysecret"
```

with the second one being:

```
- kind: Secret
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: mysecret
    creationTimestamp:
  data:
    WebHookSecretKey: c2VjcmV0dmFsdWUx
```

(2) If I query `oc describe bc [name-of-my-build-config]`, I get (all masks of `[this]` form were added by me)

```
Webhook GitHub:
    URL:    https://[blabla].openshift-online.com:6443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/[my-namespace]/buildconfigs/[my-build-config]/webhooks/<secret>/github
```

So now when I enter this url as a GitHub webhook, what should I replace `<secret>` with in the above URL? Also, what should I enter in the textbox for Secret on Github (see screenshot below)

[image]

I understand that the `WebHookSecretKey: c2VjcmV0dmFsdWUx` is just an encoded version of the plaintext secret key... So where should I use the plaintext key? Should I also use `mysecret` anywhere, eg substitute in for `<secret>` in the above url?

Comment: So `oc describe bc` gives you the URL...then `oc get bc -o yaml` will give you the value to fill in for `<secret>`

Comment: @WillGordon, ah this is much easier than the what the docs suggest... it solved my problem, please could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the *full* GitHub Webhook URL in OpenShift 4.x is to first get the URL from

```
$ oc describe bc my-build

...
Webhook GitHub:
    URL:    https://api.example.com:6443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/my-project/buildconfigs/my-build/webhooks/<secret>/github
...
```

Then, to fill in the `<secret>` portion of the URL, you get this from

```
$ oc get bc -o yaml

...
  triggers:
  - github:
      secret: 467ed550-c447-411d-87ad-2d3a3fa81538
    type: GitHub
...
```

So, for this example, the GitHub Webhook URL would be

`https://api.example.com:6443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/my-project/buildconfigs/my-build/webhooks/467ed550-c447-411d-87ad-2d3a3fa81538/github`

Comment: So I am doing what you sugest, but when I test the webhook nothing happens. I do oc describe bc/<bcName> | grep Triggered and I get Triggered by: <none> Do you have an idea why did could happen?

Comment: Is your cluster API accessible to the git instance? Assuming github.com, is your cluster API available to the public internet?

Comment: Hey Will, I had to use a generic trigger type instead of a gitlab. That was the issue.